# How can I check if all panels of a playing board were visited by the player?

Tags: java

I am working on an exercise from Mooc.fi's java part 2, week 10. It is called Dungeon.
Basically you have a playing board(created with a String[][] array) and a player that moves on it. The size of the board(lenght and height) can be set when starting the game.

If you pass a string containing the letters "wasd" the player will change position accordingly and reappear on the board as long as the move is within the bounds. If not, the command that would set the player out of bounds is ignored but the rest is still executed.
So if the user enters "wasd" and s would carry the player out of bounds, only "wad" is actually executed.

The player will only reappear on the new position if the entire command entered has been processed.

Now, you either win if you hunted down all the enemies, or if the player has been to all the pannels of the board. But I'm not sure how I can check that the player has been to all possible positions on the board?

I figured I could use a List containing HashMaps with all the coordinates of the board and compare that with a similar list that contains all the moves the player made, but that does not seem to work.

Here is the method that sets up the board. This is also where I figured I could get all possible coordinates of the board from, I stored them in a list called boardPlaces:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = ".";
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> values = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
            values.put(i,j);
            this.boardPlaces.add(values);
        }
    }
```

And this is the player method where the string entered for the movement of the player is processed and the player moves are recorded:

```
public void updatePosition(String m)
{
    
    char[] c = m.toCharArray();
    playerMoves = new String[c.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
    {
        playerMoves[i] = String.valueOf(c[i]);
    }
    
    for(String move : playerMoves)
    {
        if(move.equals("w") && y-1 >= 0)
        {
            this.y--;
        }
        if(move.equals("s") && y+1 <= height-1)
        {
            this.y++;
        }
        if(move.equals("a") && x-1 >= 0)
        {
            this.x--;
        }
        if(move.equals("d") && x+1 <= length-1)
        {
            this.x++;
        }
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> values = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        values.put(x,y);
        movesRecorded.add(values);
    }
    moves--;
}
```

And this here is where I check if all pannels of the board have actually been visited by the player.

```
int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    this.playerMovesRecorded = player.getMovesRecorded();
    for(HashMap map : boardPlaces)
    {
        counter1++;
    }
    for(HashMap map : playerMovesRecorded)
    {
        counter2++;
    }
    return (counter1 == counter2) /*and contents of lists are the same*/|| vamps.isEmpty();
```

I figured if the number of elements is correct and the content matches it should return true -> player has visited all boards.
But I'm not sure how I should go about comparing the content of the two lists?

Comment: The best way is to simply loop through the list of all available squares, and check if the movement record contains that square, if not then return false immediately, or if they have all been visited then the loop will reach the end and you can return true.

Comment: @sorifiend how would you store the available squares? in a list or a hashmap?

Comment: Any of those would work, or the answer below from ControlAltDel works well.

Comment: @sorifiend I used a HashMap, it worked, thank you! I guess I was overcomplicating the issue at hand.

Comment: @morloq Have you taken a look at my answer yet? It is an object-oriented approach, which is more scalable.

Comment: @Cactusroot Not yet as sorifiend's answer already helped me out. I am rather busy at the moment, but I will take a look soon..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create a custom class or create another array to capture the information, like

```
public class BoardTile {
  String info;
  boolean visited;
}
```

And then use a `BoardTile[][]` instead of a `String[][]`

Alternatively, you could create a separate 2D array of booleans

```
private boolean[][] visited = new boolean[widthOfBoard, heightOfBoard];
```

Comment: I would not use a seperate 2D array. Always avoid having any information (including the dimensions of an array) twice, there is always a better approach (the BoardTile class in this case).

Comment: @Cactusroot re: separate 2D array. I think it depends. If you are just trying to script something up quickly (for instance you just need a one off ETL) and it's not something you anticipate needing to maintain then you might just want to make another array and not bother with class design

Answer (score 1):

**Why your Map doesn't work:**

You are using a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. For each distinct `Integer`, this map can store another `Integer` (it "maps" `Integer` to `Integer`)

Example dataset of your current `Map`:

```
{
    1: 3
    2: 5
    4: -2
}
```

This is obviously not what you want. You likely want something like this (Mapping 2 `Integer`s to a `String`:

```
{
    "1/3": "WALL"
    "2/5": "WALL"
    "4/-2": "GROUND"
}
```

Because having 2 keys isn't possible, you need a wrapper class. (Ignore `Vector` for now):

```
public interface Vector {
    int getX();

    int getY();

    default Position add(Vector other) {
        return new Position(getX() + other.getX(), getY() + other.getY());
    }

    default Position subtract(Vector other) {
        return new Position(getX() - other.getX(), getY() - other.getY());
    }
}

public record Position(int x, int y) implements Vector {
}
```

record is just an abbreviation for a class that only contains final attributes and implements `hashCode` and `equals`.

Now you can create your `Map` like this:

```
Map<Position, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Or to save a number of `Position`s the player already entered, do this:

```
Set<Position> list = new HashSet<>();
```

A `Set` can only contain each value once, so you can add the same `Position` over and over again, but it will only the first one will be saved.

**Why I would not do that:**

Java is an [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language. You can bundle information and simplify problems by using an object-oriented approach.

Let's create a few classes here to make things object-oriented:

1. Not using `String` to store non-textual data

Because the amount of different `Tile`s you have is limited anyway, you can create an enum. I assume you have 2 `Tile`s (WALL and GROUND).

```
public enum Pattern {
    GROUND,
    WALL
}
```

2. Bundling all information about a `Tile`:

```java
public class Tile {
    private final Pattern pattern; // The kind of Tile doesn't change.
    private final Position pos; // The pos doesn't change.
    private boolean visited; // Whether you entered the Tile can change.

    public Tile(Pattern pattern, Position pos) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.pos = pos;
    }
    
    public Position getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public void markVisited() {
        visited = true;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }
}
```

3. Bundling all information about a board.

- You can either apply strict boundaries to your `Board` (see getTile1),
- or make it wrap (way easier than you probably think) (see getTile2).

```java
public class Board {
    private final int width, heigth;
    private final Tile[][] tiles;

    public Board(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.tiles = new Tile[width][height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                tiles[x][y] = new Tile(Pattern.GROUND);
            }
        }
    }

    public Tile getTile1(Position pos) {
        int x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - 1, pos.getX()));
        int y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - 1, pos.getY()));
        return tiles[x][y];
    }

    public Tile getTile2(Position pos) {
        int x = Math.floorMod(x, width);
        int y = Math.floorMod(y, height);
        return tiles[x][y];
    }
}
```

4. Instead of using `String`s, make an enum `Direction`:

```java
public enum Direction implements Vector {
    UP(0, -1, 'w'), DOWN(0, 1, 's'), LEFT(-1, 0, 'a'), RIGHT(1, 0, 'd');

    private final int x, y;
    private final char keyChar;

    Direction(int x, int y, char keyChar) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.keyChar = keyChar;
    }

    public static Direction forKeyChar(char keyChar) {
        for (Direction dir : values()) {
            if (dir.keyChar == keyChar) return dir;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Direction for keyChar " + keyChar);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

**How powerful this is:**

1. Updating the player position (I assume you chose either `getTile1` or `getTile2` already and called it simply `getTile`)

```java
private Board board = new Board();
private Tile playerTile = board.getTile(new Position(x, y));
```

Code to update:

For each key pressed, you can now add all of the `Direction`s together to obtain a `Position`, which acts as a `Vector`:

```
String m = ...;
Position change = new Position(0, 0);
for (char c : m.toCharArray()) pos = pos.add(Direction.forKeyChar(c));
Tile newPlayerPos = board.getTile(playerTile.getPos().add(change));
```

2. Solve your problem

Add this method into `Board`:

```
public boolean allVisited() {
    for (int y = 0; y <= height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= height; x++) {
            if (!tiles[x][y].isVisited()) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note: I didn't check any of the code, hope it works!